# Checking if a woocommerce attribute is set

Tags: plugins, terms, conditional-tags

I'm trying to figure out how I can check if a custom attribute is set in woocommerce on a product. As It generates an error if that particular attribute isn't set.

Here is my code that pulls in the attribute.

```
<?php 
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'pa_size');
        if ( isset ($terms)) // checking if the att is set
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo "<li>" .$term->name. "</li>";
         } 


         ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check this by using:

```
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    //your code
}
```

Take a look at the codex page for [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) for a deeper insight, especially the »Returns« and »Examples« section.

Comment: You really should be working for woocommerce iaocin. Your understanding of the system has been brilliant in regard to my project

Comment: You again :) you should change your name to something one could possibly remember. I'm happy as it is, free and unbound. Beside that, it's barely a woocommerce related problem, rather a general one. @user2478101

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) in Codex under Returns:

> Array of term objects on success. **False if no terms are found** in the given taxonomy and a wp_error object if an invalid taxonomy is entered.

So your test for `isset` passes when there are no terms, because `false` is a value.

Comment: I feel like together it'd be or is the perfect answer.

Comment: I can only mark one I'm afraid. However it explains lots to me, I'll still a rookie with php haha!